# Say hallo to many people: 你好 or 你们好?

Tags: grammar

If a meet you (singular), I say "你好".

If I meet you (plural), shall I say "你们好", instead?

Comment: This has been asked as http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5538/is-%E4%BD%A0%E4%BB%AC%E5%A5%BD-n%C7%90men-h%C7%8Eo-in-actual-use-for-greeting-multiple-people-at-once

But the answers there are not very complete.

Comment: irib.ir 亲爱的听众朋友，你们好！

Answer (score 3):

You may also use: 诸位好！or 各位好!

There may be more, Chinese has a lot of ways to express things!

Answer (score 2):

大家好 is more common, methinks. 你好 is more for personal interaction, and not very common in group settings.